# Defining Binary Macros in C++

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

Can someone explain why the following error happens:

```
    #define bla "\xA"
    char a [2] = {0};
    memcpy (a,bla,1); // a[0] = 0x0a <- Correct
    //a[1] = bla;     // '=' : cannot convert from 'const char [2]' to 'char'
```

Thanks,

RM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
#define bla '\xA'
```

Although that will stop the `memcpy` working.

Comment: Bingo.

So if I use " " it treats it creates a null terminated array of char
and if I user ' ' it just treats it like a char right ?

Answer (score 5):

The types are different: a[1] is a char and "\xA" is an array of char.

In C++ and C anything enclosed in double quotes (including nothing) is an array of char.

Comment: Yes but should char[1] assigned to char work ?
and why is it a char [2] array ?

Comment: You're declaring a string which implicitly has a terminating zero character (U+0000) at the end, so "x" is two characters: x and \0

Comment: I thought \xA is treated as single byte i.e bla should be a single byte (char) array ?  I thought \xA is treated a single byte i.e bla should be a single byte (char) array ? – Roman M 0 secs ago  [delete this comment]

Comment: Don't forget that all strings are terminated with \0, so even if you assign a single char in the string its still two.

Comment: \xA is a single byte, but since you put it in double quotes and not single quotes, it is treated as a string (not a character) and so has an implicit nul byte after it to terminate the string.